# Parameter index out of range ( 2 number of parameters,which is 1)

Tags: java, mysql

I got this problem in my code java.sql.Exception: Parameter index out of range ( 2 number of parameters,which is 1).

This is my code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t201835006","root","p73421231");
        
        String mysql = "insert into books (bookName,Author,Perinting,Available) VALUES ('?','?',?,'True')";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(mysql);
        pstmt.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
        pstmt.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"insertion successful");
```

I tried :
"insert into books  VALUES ('?','?',?,'True')";
"insert into books  VALUES (?,?,?,'True')";
but it didn'T work.

My other codes in same project includes same databases but it works. I want to share iw for you:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t201835006","root","p73421231");
        
        String sql ="insert into customerinfo values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1,jTextField3.getText());
        pstmt.setString(2,jTextField1.getText());
        pstmt.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()));
        pstmt.setString(4,jTextField4.getText());
        
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"insertion successful");
      
        new Menu().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
```

I don't know why the first code doesn't work help me.

Comment: Show `books` table definition please

Comment: You should change your query from `insert into books (bookName,Author,Perinting,Available) VALUES ('?','?',?,'True')` to `insert into books (bookName,Author,Perinting,Available) VALUES (?,?,?,'True')`